# MP3 and OGG tags in PHP

Tags: php, linux, audio, id3

Except https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ktaglib.php and http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ does anyone know of any other way to work from PHP with tags on audio files?

I need to read and write them, and KTagLib seems a little too much for the job, and also don't really get the documentation, and getID3 seems to only write ID3v1 tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are also other ID3 functions in PHP just for reading: http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/book.id3.php

You should try stable version of getID3(), there is this comment for beta:

> **v2.0.0-b5 can write only some tag formats:**
>
> ID3v1
>
> APEtag
>
> FLAC
>
> Ogg
>
> Vorbis
>
> Lyrics3

In stable, they should be supported (if the don't lie):

> **Tag formats:**
>
> ID3v1 (v1.0 & v1.1)
>
> ID3v2 (v2.2, v2.3 & v2.4)
>
> APE tags (v1 & v2)
>
> (Ogg) VorbisComment
>
> Lyrics3 (v1 & v2)

Answer (score 1):

with ktaglib:

```
$tag = new KTaglib_MPEG_File('test.mp3')->getID3v2Tag()->getFrameList();
echo "Album: " . $tag["TIT2"];
echo "Album: " . $tag["TALB"];
echo "Artist: " . $tag["TPE1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the php module for the id3 tags (sometimes you can't install modules on some hostings), you can use this function:

> http://www.barattalo.it/2010/02/22/reading-mp3-informations-with-php-id3-tags/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, to write vorbis tags to an ogg/vorbis file, [GetId3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) requires vorbiscomment installed on the server.