# Php MP3 Tag Processing

Tags: php, mp3

I  have a php script that I want to provide a list of music from. The files are named 01.mp3 02.mp3 and 03.mp3 and so on. They all have tag info. My question is how do I access that in my php script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MP3 and OGG tags in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345562/mp3-and-ogg-tags-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a script to parse the mp3 file to acces to the data.

From google:
http://getid3.sourceforge.net
http://www.codediesel.com/pear/reading-mp3-file-tags-in-php/
...