# MP3 Tag Problems

Tags: php, mp3

my songs are exported form iTunes in a ACC format then I converted them to MP3 Format.

Download link for the song: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4zod2dgj7zu8yc/01%20Hold%20On%20%28Vicetone%20Remix%29.mp3

So i wrote a program with PHP that reads the MP3-Tags, the tags are in the last 128 bit, but for some reason there where the "artist" should be is the "guest artist", but if i look at it with windows explorer the tags are correct and there are a lot more then what I can find. So my question is in particular where is the "album artist" saved and where can i find the rest of the tags, I even tried to find them with a binary editor.

Code:

```
function Read_File($dir, $file) {
    $i = 2;
    $value;

    while ($file[$i] != NULL) { 
        $size = filesize("$dir/$file[$i]");

        $handle = fopen("$dir/$file[$i]", "r");

        fread($handle, $size - 125); // Trash

        $value[$i][0] = fread($handle, 30); // Titel
        $value[$i][1] = fread($handle, 30); // Artist
        $value[$i][2] = fread($handle, 30); // Album

        fclose($handle);

        $i++;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php MP3 Tag Processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536713/php-mp3-tag-processing)

Comment: I looked ath the 2 links in that post, but its not axactly what im looking for, the problem is i dont want he "artist", i need the "album artist".

Comment: The point is that you need to read the tags using the proper procedure rather than trying to guess offsets which may not be not fixed.

Comment: okey, I'll try it that way

Comment: If you solved your problem, consider writing the solution as an answer instead of editing "Solved" into the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this Problem I used the suggestion from greg-449 and used [AMP_Id](http://www.example.com/) function to recognize the right mp3 version the file is using.